# How to check/add keys with beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
test1 = "name"
test2 = "value"

<bare>
  <key name="drs.trial.code" value="dcnAppQA"/>
</bare>
```

So I have an xml and I want to add test1 and test2 as a key under the bare section eg.

```
  <key name="name" value="value"/>
```

Before adding this to the xml, I want to check that it does not already exists, but I'm not sure how to do this with beautiful soup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the `key` by name and value inside `bare` and if `find()` returns `None` - there is no such element and you can create one:

```
test1 = "name"
test2 = "value"

bare = soup.find("bare")

if bare.find("key", {"name": test1, "value": test2}) is None:
    new_key = soup.new_tag("key")
    new_key["name"] = test1
    new_key["value"] = test2

    bare.append(new_key)
```